# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'imageWidth' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a function that makes an ajax call to an ActionResult, it sends a base64 string of an uploaded image along with some other params with information about the dimensions of the image. The data is sent to the server for resizing among other stuff. The ajax call looks like this

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                b64: data.data,
                imageWidth: data.imageWidth,
                imageHeight: data.imageHeight,
                imageOriginalWidth: data.imageOriginalWidth,
                imageOriginalHeight: data.imageOriginalHeight
            },
            
            url: '/Image/Resize',
            beforeSend: function () {
                //stuff
            },
            success: function (data) {
               //stuff
            },
            error: function (response) {
                //stuff
            }
        });
```

The data object is retrieved from a callback function that gets all the information I mentioned above. Now, I put breakpoints and made sure that the object actually has values.

I also looked at the request in Fiddler and everything looks fine. The weird thing is that this doesn't always happen. It happens only when I try to upload a gif that is too large. The error doesn't happen when a file isn't bigger than about 2MB. To clarify, I'm not sending the file, just the base64 string.

I don't know if the problem is that the `b64` string is too large or something else, but looking at the response from the server all I see is this

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'imageWidth' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Resize(System.String, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)'

Here is what the ActionResult looks like

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Resize(String b64, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int imageOriginalWidth, int imageOriginalHeight)
    {

      //.... 
    }
```

When I try and upload another file that is smaller, everything works fine and it doesn't give me this error. I'm sorry if this question has been answered before but I've looked everywhere and haven't found an answer. I've tried changing the `dataType` in the ajax call, I've tried stringifying and looked at the request headers.

> Content-Length: 4849982
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

I don't know what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, guys.

## Request

> b64 **edited out**
> imageWidth  906
> imageHeight 509
> imageOriginalWidth  500
> imageOriginalHeight 281

Comment: Can you show us the object of the one that's working and one that isn't working? If it's calling out a null entry, something isn't getting set properly so your c# is rejecting it. Another possibility is that the data type is incorrect and `int` class rejects it. You could try making everything a string on the c# side and then sending the data object as a JSON.stingifry object.

Comment: I would but the b64 string is huge, they are identical in every way except for how long the string is of course. I will update the post with what the values are in the request without the string.

Comment: If you've got it narrowed down to the space being the issue, try adding this to your web config:

<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
   <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000"></jsonSerialization>
   </webServices>
  </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the space or not, I'm just assuming since it works otherwise. That's what's driving me crazy. Anyway, I tried adding that to web.config, tried changing dataType to json and stringifying the object but the same thing happens :(

Comment: Given the error message you provided, I would say it's some issue where the scenario of a long string is too much and there fore sends a `null` value to your c# code which is where your exception gets thrown. With that being said, I would need to see it working somewhere or see the full code to help troubleshoot

Comment: Do you mean the string is sent as `null` or all the params. Here's a gist of the query string. Be warned, it's pretty long though. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/953384e40caffb8a329e8cfd6b4bc26e#file-qstring-txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this. It turns out that the default limit for the input stream buffering threshold when a request is made to the server is **4 MB**

All you need to do is to go to your `web.config` file and add the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

where "xxx" is the size you want in **KB**

For IIS 7+ you also need to add the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="xxx" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The default value is equivalent to **30 MB**